# Especially at the beginning stage, how can one teach Chinese culture and integrate cultural elements into the language class?

Tags: learning

Especially at the beginning stage, how can one teach Chinese culture and
integrate cultural elements into the language class, in order to promote a
long-term learning process?

Comment: Welcome to Chinese StackExchange. This site is for asking specific questions about the Chinese Language(s), and is unsuited to opinion-based, broad questions like this one, which will very likely be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe talk about how Chinese characters evolves from pictograph which is very intriguing and interesting:
http://www.chinasage.info/langchars.html

Also how Chinese influenced English:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_Chinese_origin

Evolution of Chinese characters:
https://www.brown.edu/about/administration/international-affairs/year-of-china/language-and-cultural-resources/introduction-chinese-characters/introduction-chinese-characters